# Partial differential of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose I have a function $f(r, \theta, p_{\mu})$ in the phase space $(q^{\mu}, p_{\mu})$. I want to determine an expression for the partial derivative w.r.t $r$, i.e. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$.

Is it true to say that,

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r} $$

?

**My confusion comes from** the $p_{\mu}$ dependence. Is the answer instead,

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_{\mu}}\frac{\partial p_{\mu}}{\partial r} $$

? But then, since $\frac{\partial p_{\mu}}{\partial r} =0$, does this reduce to the first answer?

Comment: well, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ is defined as the derivative of $f$ with respect to $r$, after fixing the other variables, namely $\theta$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: As Malkoun was getting at, no: $\theta$ can be changed independently from $r$, that's why they're separate inputs to the function.  So, $d\theta/dr$ does not make sense: derivatives tell you how changing one variable, affects another variable which depends on it.

If you have $\theta$ as a function of $r$, then you are really composing with another function and using the Chain Rule (or part of it).

Comment: Ok, but if I have $dr/d\lambda (r, \theta, p_r) $ and $d\theta /d\lambda  (r, \theta, p_\theta) $ then surely I can derive some function $d \theta / d r$?